# Writing in multiple csv files without opening/closing at each row - Python 3.5

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I have a large csv file and I am checking the second column of each row and then write this row in another csv file. I use Python 3.5.

My csv file looks like this:

```
node_1,type,node_2  
154555,intermediary,154587
1545877,president,145888
4575885,intermediary,4785774
```

I need a different csv file for each type (intermediary, president...)

```
import csv
import os.path

i = 0
list = []
with open('all_edges.csv', 'r') as edges:
    edges_reader = csv.reader(edges)
    for row in edges_reader:
        if row[1] not in list:
            list.append(row[1])
        while row[1] != list[i]:
            i += 1
        if i != 0:
            if not os.path.exists(r'./edges%d.csv' %i):
                with open('edges%d.csv' %i, "w+", newline='') as new_edges:
                    edges_writer = csv.writer(new_edges)
                    edges_writer.writerow(["node_1", "rel_type", "node_2"])
            with open('edges%d.csv' %i, "a+", newline='') as new_edges:
                edges_writer = csv.writer(new_edges)
                edges_writer.writerow(row)
            i = 0
```

Do you have any advice on how to avoid opening and closing the output files at every row.

Thanks

Comment: Keep a dictionary of file objects--then you can say `if foo not in filedict`, do stuff to open it, say `filedict[foo] = open(foofile, "w+")`, and then after that, you can write to `filedict[foo]`. You can keep a good number of files open at the same time, it's not a big deal. At the end, you can look through filedict and close them all if you want.

Comment: Well, side-note, you don't need a special case for "file does not exist"; `a` is perfectly happen to create a file if it doesn't exist (you don't need `a+` even, since you're only writing to it, not reading from it), so you can just eliminate that `if not os.path.exists(r'./edges%d.csv' %i):` check and the whole block it controls.

Comment: Thank you, it's a lot faster now.